# Is there a standard warranty period for drywall texture in Florida?

Tags: ceiling

I am evaluating proposals to apply knockdown ceiling to a 25 year old ceiling in Florida.  Is there a standard warranty period or a reasonable warranty period for this this job / type of work?

Comment: Most contractors give a 1 year warranty on their workmanship for most trades.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't really deal with warranty advice here.